# How to install VMware Tools on Fedora 15?

Tags: vmware, fedora

Where is the best place to find resources on how to install VMware Tools on a Fedora guest? I had some trouble with Fedora 14 in the past and now I'm trying Fedora 15.

The host is Windows and I am using VMware Workstation as the hypervisor.

Comment: What have you already tried?  [Here's a step by step for Fedora 14](http://www.sysprobs.com/fedora-14-vmware-install-vmware-tools-fedora-14), the process should be pretty similar on 15.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial: [Installing VMWare Tools on Fedora](http://install-climber.blogspot.com/2011/05/installing-vmware-tools-on-fedora.html).

Answer (score 1):

VMTools on Fedora should work.

If you have the option of installing *Managed VMware Tools* from *VM Workstation* then you also need to install *Development Tools* and `kernel-devel` to compile the tools yourself.

Otherwise try [these RPMs](http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/4.1/rhel6/index.html) for unmanaged support. The same is true for *VMware ESX*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me on Fedora35

I have - VMware-Workstation-Full-15.5.6-16341506.x86_64.bundle

git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules

cd vmware-host-modules

git checkout workstation-15.5.6

sudo make ; sudo make install